# Translating strings that are outside of the range of gettext

Tags: python-3.x, translation, external, gettext, xgettext

I'm implementing get text on my Discord bot and I have a few strings that come from configuration files for example: Regions where the game is from (Global server, Korean server, Japanese server, Asia server, etc.) that I want to also be translated into. Since these files are stored as JSON, I can't really use get text on them.

So I was wondering what can I do to get these strings translated? I came up with a few approaches that would solve my problem but they don't look that nice to me.

### Method 1 - Use .py files for these settings

This one is self explanatory. I can use python modules to store the configuration for that, which would allow me to use the _(...) get text function which would allow xgettext to pick up the strings to be translated.

### Method 2 - Hard code the strings

This would come in two ways, hardcoding them inside the module they're going to be used on or in a module where I would hard code all the strings that come from external data sources.

Is there any better approach to tackle this?

Answer (score 1):

Extract the strings from the configuration files into an additional `.pot` file like `config.pot`. You can then pass this file as an additional input file to `xgettext` because `xgettext` will always recognize `.po` or `.pot` files as input regardless of the programming language.